# Typescript defining a type holds both array of object and arrays

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out how can I define a type of array contains objects array and array or objects keys as elements :

```
export type iFormInputTest = {
  name: string
  type: 'textInput' | 'Select'
}

export type iFormInputsTest= {
  button: {
    label: string
    style?: { [key: string]: any }
  }
  data: iFormInputTest[] | iFormInputTest[][]
}

const inputs: iFormInputsTest = {
  button: {
    label: 'Submit'
  },
  data: [
    {
      name: 'input1',
      type: 'textInput'
    },
    [
      {
        name: 'input2',
        type: 'textInput'
      },
      {
        name: 'input3',
        type: 'Select'
      }
    ],
    {
      name: 'input4',
      type: 'textInput'
    }
]}
```

This is the type error I get :

> Type '({ name: string; type: "textInput"; } | ({ name: string; type:
> "textInput"; } | { name: string; type: "Select"; })[])[]' is not
> assignable to type 'iFormInputTest[] | iFormInputTest[][]'.   Type '({
> name: string; type: "textInput"; } | ({ name: string; type:
> "textInput"; } | { name: string; type: "Select"; })[])[]' is not
> assignable to type 'iFormInputTest[]'.
> Type '{ name: string; type: "textInput"; } | ({ name: string; type: "textInput"; } | { name: string; type: "Select"; })[]' is not
> assignable to type 'iFormInputTest'.
> Type '({ name: string; type: "textInput"; } | { name: string; type: "Select"; })[]' is missing the following properties from type
> 'iFormInputTest': name, type

I tried everything but I wasn't able to find a way to define a `data` key holds both array of `iFormInputTest` objects and recursive array of `iFormInputTest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not sure about the reason, but it it fixable by declaring the type like this:

```
export type iFormInputsTest= {
  // ...
  data: Array<iFormInputTest | iFormInputTest[]>
}
```

-- Edit--

On a second thought, it actually makes sense for it to fail. You have a union type which means that either you have a property which is `iFormInputTest[]` or your property must be `iFormInputTest[][]` but not mixed. The way you can mix them is as I stated, having an array of either `iFormInputTest` or `iFormInputTest[]`.

You can have the same result with this syntax (in case you prefer it):

```
export type iFormInputsTest= {
  // ...
  data: (iFormInputTest | iFormInputTest[])[]
}
```

Comment: Yes, no complaints from TS now. I didn't know that I can wrap them in array this way, I appreciate it